# Any way to parse Less in .net?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, less

Last day in job I got pretty hard task. My task is to make new theme for our project (website). New theme should be rewritten to be fully responsive (actually it isn't). I have decided to use **Bootstrap** framework, because it is seems to be pretty nice, easy to learn and have good documentation with examples.

Today after reading most of documentation I tried to implement this. The only problem is that I tried to use it's main Less based version (which seems to have better support, cuz is main) to get better customizable themes (each theme can have it's own ***variables.less*** file) and I did not found good **Less** parser that work with **.net MVC3**.

Using JS to parse Bootstrap in not an option, because some of our customers have pretty old computers (Windows XP + IE8). I have tried to use **dotless** as a parser, but it had problems to handle **Bootstrap**, had problems with relative paths (problem with ***@include*** instruction) and was unable to load files from different directories (***variables.less*** is in theme directory when rest of **Bootstrap** is shared).

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful, cuz today I spent ~8h and did totaly nothing.

Comment: Do you know what Less actually is? You don't parse it, you compile Less files into classic CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try http://vswebessentials.com/

This nice Visual Studio plugin support LESS out of the box.
(http://vswebessentials.com/features/less)

[image]